# Hey, meta. I know this is crazy, but here's an idea, let's rename [maybe]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[maybe](/questions/tagged/maybe) **× 42**

This seems a little vague and it was being used for "yes/no/maybe" questions. I deleted those and started down the road of language specific ones, but it's a very generic functional programming structure. The majority are [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), but the rest are split among several languages.

[maybe](/questions/tagged/maybe) **+** [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) **× 29**

I suggest we <strike>rename it either [maybe-monad](/questions/tagged/maybe-monad) or [monads-maybe](/questions/tagged/monads-maybe) ([monads](/questions/tagged/monads) **× 713** already exists).</strike>  **burninate** it.

Comment: I have *just* the right renaming device in mind. http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/flamethrower.jpg

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's always a good option, as well.

Comment: -1 for getting the song stuck in my head :(

Comment: I was only going to leave that up for a second and forgot to rollback. * shrug *

Comment: @ThinkingStiff - I'm slow today it took mea  awhile to catch that .  Off to Youtube

Comment: @Adel lol @ your name (you get the relation?). I think we should move this question to Music.SE. (Hey, just joking)

Comment: Retagging to `maybe-monad` only makes sense for those questions that are actually about using `Maybe` as a monad. Most of them aren't. Either leave it as it is, or just remove it.

Comment: Include the [haskell] tag with your search.

Comment: @hammar I don't know Haskell at all, so I'll take your word for it. If it's just a class, I guess burning it is the best option.

Comment: I'm not sure, [tag:maybe]...